# Infinite recursion with Qt coupled signal/slot

Tags: qt, qt4, signals-slots

I think I have some fundamental misunderstanding of how the Qt signal/slot mechanism works.

I have worked through example programs and they make sense but when I've tried to take those and modify them I have been getting results I do not understand. I have attach a code sample below that is a boiled-down version of what I was trying to do that certainly does not do what I want it to.  Am I misusing the signal/slot mechanism and or the `QString` class?  Is the way I am using the signal/slot to modify things in a coupled fashion creating an infinite loop?  Any help greatly appreciated.

```
// test.cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QString>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

class myDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
      myDialog() : a_( new QLineEdit ), b_( new QLineEdit )
      {
        QVBoxLayout* layout( new QVBoxLayout( this ) );
        layout->addWidget( a_ );
        layout->addWidget( b_ );

        connect( a_, SIGNAL( textChanged( const QString& ) ),
                 this, SLOT( aChanged( const QString& ) ) );
        connect( b_, SIGNAL( textChanged( const QString& ) ),
                 this, SLOT( bChanged( const QString& ) ) );
    }

    private:
      QLineEdit* a_;
      QLineEdit* b_;

    private slots:
      void aChanged( const QString& qs );
      void bChanged( const QString& qs );    
};
#include "test.moc"

void myDialog::aChanged( const QString& qs )
{
  b_->setText( QString::number( 2.0 * qs.toDouble() ) );
}

void myDialog::bChanged( const QString& qs )
{
  a_->setText( QString::number( 3.3 * qs.toDouble() ) );
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    QApplication a( argc, argv );
    myDialog d;
    d.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because In aChanged, you edit the b QLineEdit, it triggers the textChanged() signal for b...causing it to call bChanged, changing a..... etc. etc.

I think that is your problem here.

You might want to use [textEdited()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#textEdited) in stead.

Comment: I thought maybe that was causing a problem.  If that is so, how do you achieve changing the value of "b" only once for a change to "a"?

Comment: use the textEdited() signal instead of textChanged().

Comment: @bpw1621 although _technically_ your problem was explained already, your code still seems conceptually wrong and just switching to textEdited might hide the error.  It seems like you want `b` to always contain a number which is 2.0 times the number in `a`, and you want `a` to always contain a number which is 3.3 times the number in `b`, which is not possible.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed this too, but assumed it was just a quick test to clearly see the difference between the methods called. Normally there should be a proper relationship. (If it's just a test, a Celcius/Farenheit conversion comes to mind)

Comment: @Friend-Pal Bart was right that it was just a simple example: the real application does coordinate transformation between geocentric and geodetic frames but I thought the math-iness of the code would obscure the real question.  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score -1):

Not so critical in this case, but please pay attention to delete a_ and b_ in the destructor since they dont have any parent.

Comment: From the docs regarding addWidget: The ownership of item is transferred to the layout, and it's the layout's responsibility to delete it.